# How are filter strides implemented (coding wise) in CNNs?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, python-imaging-library, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to figure out how strides are coded in CNNs and I can't seem to implement it efficently -- the script takes a long time to finish the calculations or I run into errors

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('C:\sample_pic.jpeg').convert("RGB") #800 x600 dimensions
pixels =np.array(img)  # However PIL inverts height and width so #600 X800
print(pixels.shape)    # (600L, 800L, 3L)
```

Ideally I don't want to flatten the image, but I couldn't figure out how to multiply a 600 x 800 x 3 image with a filter of 2x3x3 when using a stride of 1 correctly. So I attempted to flatten the array as I felt it would be easier.

```
   flat = pixels.flatten()
   filter1= np.array([1,1,0],) 
   pixels2 = np.array([])

for i in range(0, len(flat),2):
   pixels2 =np.append(pixels2,np.sum((flat[i:i+3] * filter1)))
```

So I attempting to multiply the RGB values of each pixel with the filter, and then taking the sum and then sliding by 2. I'm trying to visualize the first convolutional layer of a CNN. 
  Here I can't figure out how to tell the loop to only iterate if i+3 elements are available.  I think this is the reason why I'm getting the following error

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (3,)`

Also is there is a computationally faster way to multiply the filter values with the image's pixels values, as it's taking a long time on my laptop to compute. (Intel i-7 3610QM @2.30 Geforce 650M GT 2GB)

EDIT:  Editing for clarity. If it's possible to multiply the 600x800x3 array with a filter of 2x3x3, then I want to use a stride of 1. 
I want the filter to look something like this,

```
[[[1,1,0]
[1,1,0]
[1,1,0]]


[[1,1,0]
[1,1,0]
[1,1,0]]]
```

2 rows each with 3 columns each columns has three values [1,1,0]

The original image is 600 rows (height), 800 columns (width) and 3 values ( RGB values).

Sorry for any confusion.

Image I'm using:

[image]

Comment: What would be the shape of the output array?

Comment: Hi, Ideally I want an output that can be reshaped to dimensions that are natural for picture dimensions.  So I want to be able to reshape to 350 (minimum) for each dimension if possible.

Comment: To solve your loopy code, maybe try : `for i in range(0, len(flat)-2,2):`?

Comment: Adding a -2 should work but I'm looking for a more general line of code that would work irrespective of  the image's original dimensions. Thanks.

Comment: Modify your loopy code to make it work with `2x3x3` shaped filter, as that seems to be the *final destination*? You stated - `"RGB values of each pixel with the filter,"`. With a multi-dim filter, there are various ways to interpret the filtering operation. So, a loopy code would help demo what's on your mind.

Comment: Are you trying to convolve the `(2, 2, 3)` with the `(600, 800, 3)`? Do you want to do this separately for each color plane, producing a `(599, 799, 3)` output, or all together, producing a `(599, 799)` output? Or did you mean a stride of 2, giving `(300, 400, 3)` or `(300, 400)`?

Comment: Sorry, for the confusion. I want a stride of 1 when the image isn't flattened. I want an output of 3-dimensions. So I'm assuming  (599,799,3) would be the output if I used a stride of 1 with a filter of (2,3,3). Thank you.

Comment: You didn't answer what would be the output shape with a stride of say `2` or `3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Not the most optimal solution, as it incurs a copy in `stack`,</s><sup>1</sup>. but:

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

res = np.stack([
    convolve2d(pixels[...,i], filter[...,i], mode='valid')
    for i in range(3)
], axis=-1)
```

or to eliminate the magic number `3`:

```
res = np.stack([
    convolve2d(plane, filterp, mode='valid')
    for plane, filterp in zip(np.rollaxis(pixels, -1), np.rollaxis(filter, -1))
], axis=-1)
```

<sup>1 - actually, since convolve2d has no `out` argument, there's no alternative</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about convolve2d. It will take some time as I will read about first convolve2d, but I will play around with the code you gave and see if I have any questions. Thank you.

Comment: So I was testing the code, and I ran into a couple of problems:
`'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\PIL_Image.py", line 38, in <module>
    assert res.shape == (599, 799, 3)
AssertionError` which I don't think is much of a problem as when I check the res shape I get( 599,798, 3). However, when I try to convert it back to image format using im = Image.fromarray(res), I seem to be getting an error, `TypeError: Cannot handle this data type`. Any clue why I might be betting the error?

Comment: @moondra: I misread your filter shape as (2, 2, 3), not (2, 3, 3). Yes, that assertion is garbage. Your issue is probably that `res` has dtype float, whereas `Image.fromarray` is likely expecting `uint8`

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about that. Thanks.

Comment: Everything works great, but I'm having trouble understanding your usage of np.stack with axis -1, and why you choose i to be the RGB values with a range of 3.   I looked over the docs for stack, but I'm still not getting it why it's essential in this case intuitively.

Comment: `stack(...,axis = -1)` turns N arrays of shape `(a, b, c, ...)` into one array of shape `(a, b, c, ..., N)` - putting `N` in the -1th position. The range is `3` because `len('rgb') == 3`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with [`Scipy's 2D convolution`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) and incorporating stride -

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d as conv2

def filter_images3D(img3D, filter3D, stride=1):
    M1,N1 = img3D.shape[:2]
    M2,N2 = filter3D.shape[:2]
    O1,O2 = (M1-M2+stride)//stride, (N1-N2+stride)//stride

    n = img3D.shape[-1]
    out = np.empty((O1,O2,n))
    for i in range(n):
        out[...,i] = conv2(img3D[...,i],filter3D[...,i],'valid')[::stride,::stride]
    return out
```

Comment: That's not what stride means for convolution, sadly. Stride would mean `conv(img, filter)[::stride]`, but obviously you want to do that without calculating the values that are discarded

Comment: @Eric That's right, missed out on that earlier. Updated.

Comment: Thanks I'm going to read about the convolve2d (never used it) first, and then play around with the code.